# Tinkter Not Setting Color Properly

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

I am new to Python, and very new to Tinkter. I am trying to wright an application to track burned out light bulbs. I want a grid of yellow boxes that turn grey once clicked. I am trying to debug an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\new2.py", line 32, in <module>
    draw_rectangles()
  File "C:\Python32\new2.py", line 29, in draw_rectangles
    cell_zone.create_rectangle(place, 25, place+25, 50, fill=color)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2194, in create_rectangle
    return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2173, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "42593256color"
```

---

The "42593256color" shows a different random number every time.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

columns = 5
clicked = False

cell_zone = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
cell_zone.pack()

def color():
    if clicked == True:
        #color = "grey"
        pass
    if clicked == False:
        #color = "yellow"
        pass


def draw_rectangles():
    for i in range(1, columns+1):
        place = i * 50
        print(place)
        #cell_zone.create_rectangle(place, place, place*1.2, place*1.2, fill="yellow")
        #cell_zone.create_rectangle(25, 25, 50, 50, fill="yellow")
        #cell_zone.create_rectangle(75, 25, 100, 50, fill="green")
        #cell_zone.create_rectangle(125, 25, 150, 50, fill="pink")
        #cell_zone.create_rectangle(place, 25, place+25, 50, fill="yellow", command=button_color())
        print(color)
        cell_zone.create_rectangle(place, 25, place+25, 50, fill=color)

color()
draw_rectangles()


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `color` is a function, perhaps you intendeded to do this:

```
cell-zone.create_rectangle(...fill=color())
```

Note the use of `()` to call the function to get the color. Though, since `color()` doesn't actually return a color, that will fail too.

Do you intend for `color` to hold a color, return a color, or something else?